# Org-mode Plant UML issue

Tags: emacs, org-mode, plantuml, org-babel

I am using PlantUML inside my org file to generate UML diagrams.  When I try to create **generalization** relationship by

```
#+begin_src plantuml :file generalization-plantuml.png :exports none
Elective ^-- Subject
#+end_src
```

I getting error as

```
Dot executable: /opt/local/bin/dot
File does not exist.
Cannot find Graphiz. You should try
@startuml
testdot
@enduml
or
java -jar plantuml.jar -testdot
```

Any clue, where I am doing wrong.

I also tried

```
Elective <|-- Subject
```

but, it also giving the same error.

Comment: Did you install the graphviz dot program ? Just type in a terminal window `which dot` and `dot --version`.

Comment: It was an issue of graphviz.  I installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to export class diagram, Graphviz is a must for plantuml.jar.

You can refer to [plantuml official site](https://plantuml.com/starting)

Comment: Yes, I did.  But after asking the question.  But I have another doubt.  The simple association `class1 --> class2` is not producing the desired result as shown in the plantuml site.  Can you help?

Comment: I don't know what's your problem then. so i offer some steps to check.

1)  java -jar plantuml.jar -testdot                                                                                                        
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx500m
Dot version: dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
Installation seems OK. File generation OK

If you get the prompts like above, it is ok for installation of graphviz. please take care about the version of graphviz. you can follow the instructions in https://plantuml.com/faq

Comment: 2) open a png file manually in emacs to check if it can be shown.

3) run emacs in debug mode to get detailed error information. I suggest you export a svg file then you can check the output xml manually. I ran into a issue before that "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx500m" will cause export failed.

I hope these will help you.